# PHP download resume not work in firefox

Tags: php

I have this code for download file from my server :

```
require('../config.php');




// sanitize the file request, keep just the name and extension
// also, replaces the file location with a preset one ('./myfiles/' in this example)

$file_path  = '123.mp3';
$path_parts = pathinfo($file_path);
$file_name  = $path_parts['basename'];
$file_ext   = $path_parts['extension'];
$file_path  = ABSPATH.'/uploads/files/1/' . $file_name;




// allow a file to be streamed instead of sent as an attachment
$is_attachment = isset($_REQUEST['stream']) ? false : true;

// make sure the file exists
    if (is_file($file_path))
{
    $file_size  = filesize($file_path);
    $file = fopen($file_path,"rb");
    if ($file)
    {
        // set the headers, prevent caching
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: -1");
        header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");

        // set appropriate headers for attachment or streamed file
        if ($is_attachment) {
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file_name\"");
        }
        else {
                header('Content-Disposition: inline;');
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        }

        // set the mime type based on extension, add yours if needed.
        $ctype_default = "application/octet-stream";
        $content_types = array(
                "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
                "zip" => "application/zip",
                "mp3" => "audio/mpeg",
                "mpg" => "video/mpeg",
                "avi" => "video/x-msvideo",
        );
        $ctype = isset($content_types[$file_ext]) ? $content_types[$file_ext] : $ctype_default;
        header("Content-Type: " . $ctype);

        //check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
        if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
        {
            list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
            {
                //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
                //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
                list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
            }
            else
            {
                $range = '';
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                exit;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $range = '';
        }

        //figure out download piece from range (if set)
        list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

        //set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
        //also check for invalid ranges.
        $seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($file_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($file_size - 1));
        $seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

        //Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
        if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($file_size - 1))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$file_size);
            header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
        }
        else
          header("Content-Length: $file_size");

        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

        set_time_limit(0);
        fseek($file, $seek_start);

        while(!feof($file)) 
        {
            print(fread($file, 1024*8));
            ob_flush();
            flush();
            if (connection_status()!=0) 
            {
                fclose($file);
                exit;
            }           
        }

        // file save was a success
        fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
        // file couldn't be opened
        header("HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error");
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    // file does not exist
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
```

In Action, pause download worked in chrome but in Firefox pause download is failed and when click retry icon i see false volume like this :

[image]

how do fix this problem?!

Comment: Why do you have a bunch of error suppression operators (`@`)?

Comment: What's the value of `$is_attachment`?

Comment: This looks like you have cobbled together various scripts/tutorials some of which were probably to do with emailing attachments. **Best start again**

Comment: You're at least setting two `Content-Disposition` headers, possibly conflicting ones.  What is the actual result of headers being sent from the server?

Comment: you need to do all of your ini settings **BEFORE** you run anything else. e.g. you're doing your require before the changes, so any errors/warnings from that code will STILL be output. and using `@` to suppress errors is the coding equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalala can't hear you".

Comment: @MarcB: u and other right, i fix my problem with remove `@` and change my question for new problem.